# splitting of binaries

Tags: erlang

I tried to split two fields from a binary string:

```
-define(S,<<"M\0\0\0522039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,‌​0110,00,150,0,0,0\0">>).<<Message_length:4/binary,Msg/binary>> = S.
```

the first 4 bytes are the length of the following message, the other byte are the message,
a null byte terminates the string.

The result is:
** exception error: o match of right hand side value
EDIT
Just before the given code, there is:

```
[Sequence|Reste] = binary:split(T,<<"\0">>),
```

Does "Reste" bounded ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is ok, so either you dont have a binary string, or the length of Mystring does not comply with the pattern. Here's a quick test:

```
1> Mystring = <<"abcde">>.
<<"abcde">>
2> <<Message_length:4/binary,Msg/binary>> = Mystring.
<<"abcde">>
3> Message_length.
<<"abcd">>
4> Msg.
<<"e">>
```

If you have a string (a list of integers) instead of a binary string (<<"string">>), as Vincenzo suggested, call erlang:list_to_binary/1 first.

Hope it helps

EDIT: I've checked the example string you left in a comment of Vincenzo's answer. I've tried it with your code and still works. Is it possible that Message_length and/or Msg are already bound (and different to Mystring) when reaching that line of code? That would make the pattern matching fail.

EDIT2: Tested with the updated data in the question:

```
1> S = <<"M\0\0\0522039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,\342\200\214\342\200\2130110,00,150,0,0,0\0">>.
<<77,0,0,42,50,48,51,57,51,53,53,48,57,57,44,48,49,48,49,
  48,48,48,48,48,48,48,56,44,48,...>>
2> <<Message_length:4/binary,Msg/binary>> = S.
<<77,0,0,42,50,48,51,57,51,53,53,48,57,57,44,48,49,48,49,
  48,48,48,48,48,48,48,56,44,48,...>>
3> Message_length.
<<77,0,0,42>>
4> Msg.
<<"2039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,\342"...>>
```

Comment: Yep, knowing the string now I agree with you that it should be a pattern rebound mistake on Message_length and Msg. Same result as yours on R15B01 (tested).

Comment: After 77 there are two nulls, in S three nulls !!? I don't understand the notion of pattern rebound.

Comment: @Bertaud \OOO is actually looking for 3 numbers, which specify a 3 digit octal number. So in this case you have octals: 0, 0, 052 (42 in decimal). A pattern rebound means that you are trying to re-assign a value to an already bound variable, which will cause the error you mention if those values are not exactly the same

Comment: I test with emacs. After each modif I recompile and run the code. My variables should not be rebounded ? M\0\0\0 are the 4-bytes length: the length is 77 bytes (77 = M)

Comment: Message_length should be <<77,0,0,0>> not <<77,0,0,42>>

Comment: @Bertaud Then your binary is wrong. It should start with: M\000\000\000. The code works in the shell as it is. It should work on your module too.

Answer (score 1):

There is issue with erlang string escape interpolation. The fourth byte is not interpolated as `"\0"` but `"\052"`.

```
1> Bin = <<"M\0\0\0522039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,0110,00,150,0,0,0\0">>.
<<77,0,0,42,50,48,51,57,51,53,53,48,57,57,44,48,49,48,49,                                                                                                                     
  48,48,48,48,48,48,48,56,44,48,...>>
```

So you have to write it in this manner.

```
2> f().
ok
3> Bin = <<"M\0\0\0","522039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,0110,00,150,0,0,0\0">>.
<<77,0,0,0,53,50,50,48,51,57,51,53,53,48,57,57,44,48,49,
  48,49,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,56,...>>
```

Then usual way to parse this form of messages is:

```
4> <<L:32/little,Rest/binary>> = Bin.
<<77,0,0,0,53,50,50,48,51,57,51,53,53,48,57,57,44,48,49,
  48,49,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,56,...>>
5> L.
77
6> <<Msg:L/binary,R/binary>> = Rest.
<<"522039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,0110,00,150,0,0,0"...>>
7> R.
<<0>>
8> Msg.
<<"522039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,0110,00,150,0,0,0">>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `list_to_binary/1` on string to be matched.

If you have further problems, type example string please!

Comment: -define(S,<<"M\0\0\0522039355099,010100000008,0,010170000000,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,0110,00,150,0,0,0\0">>).

Comment: @Bertaud is this the content of Mystring? Can you update the question with this example?